# How get css rules (class declarations) from stylesheets across all desktop and mobile browsers back to IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I need to get all class (and nested class) declarations from a stylesheet in IE8+ as well as the modern browsers. In modern browsers this is easy with:

```
document.styleSheets[ 0 ][ "cssRules" ];
```

but this doesn't work in IE8. How would I make this work in IE8 (which does have document.stylesheets)?

Comment: use rules instead of cssRules

Comment: @dandavis will that return the same information? e.g. `rules[ 0 ].selectorText`? If yes, can you make that an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Comment: it will return similar information, don't you just love IE?

Comment: Can you please post as an answer so I can mark this answered?